# make java type out a string on keyboard

Tags: java, string

I am working on a project. I want a user string (no trouble with that) to be typed out by java. Is that possible and if yes, then how?

Thank you!
I don't blame for the down votes

Comment: `I want a user string to be typed out by java.` What are you asking?

Comment: `System.out.println()'? Is that what you mean?

Comment: not on the console.

Comment: then where do you want your software to display the message ?

Comment: @spytasticspytastic_ Do you mean you want to simulate key presses? Like have the program type on the keyboard for the user?

Comment: yes. simulate key presses

Comment: @spytasticspytastic_ Use the `Robot` class to simulate mouse and keyboard actions. Read the documentation to understand how to use it: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

Comment: [like this?](https://media.giphy.com/media/l41lUJ1YoZB1lHVPG/giphy.gif)

Answer (score 0):

You can't just blindly make the program type it out on the keyboard as it is not getting displayed anywhere. You have to either use some third-party module that I have no idea about that presses keys for you, or you should actually store the string somewhere, some sort of text box. If you are using a java swing to make a GUI app, then simply create a JTextBox and set the text to your string like this:

```
JTextbox textbox = new JTextbox();
textbox.setText("your string goes here");
```

Comment: `Robot` is built-in that simulates presses. Also, I'm not entirely sure this answers the question, but the question is also vague. I would have waited for more information before answering.

Comment: Does JTextBox really have publicly exposed fields like `text`? It very well could, I'm not saying it doesn't, it just looks weird in Java. Also, if the option did exist, it presumably wouldn't trigger a UI update.

Comment: @tradeJmark I think it uses `setText`. You're right, an exposed field like that would be an odd design choice.

Comment: You are both right about exposing, I just didn't initialize it in the answer cuz I was writing from my phone